# Anybody know of good material or videos to help me understand Stochastic Gradient Descent?

Tags: stochastic-gradient-descent

I am trying to understand stochastic gradient descent a bit better as I'm not 100. Does anybody have any materials or videos that they would recommend to me that might help describe the concept? I'm really trying to get a better understanding of it. I'll take this question down if it is not the right place to ask it or if this duplicate of another question. If so, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're confused about gradient descent, I would recommend this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDv4f4s2SB8

And once you've understood that, I'd recommend: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMh0zPT0tLI for stochastic gradient descent.

StatQuest makes fantastic videos and I'd highly recommend the channel in general.

Comment: Great, thank you so much!